# Connect mpcie WIFI card thru USB adapter/

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, drivers, hardware

I have WIFI card for mpcie slot connected to my computer.
Here is `lspci`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

But I need this card connected through USB. So I bought [this](http://eshop.sintech.cn/mini-pcie-3g-wlan-wireless-wifi-card-to-usb-adapter-with-sim-s-p-1030.html).

It is not working and I don't know why. If I connect this adapter and wifi card through adapter the entry appears from `lspci`.

And `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1997:7b03  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Adapter works for 100% because i tried to connect different mini Pcie device and it was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your card supports only PCIe communication while the adapter you purchased uses the USB data line only which is used by mostly all 3G mpcie form factor (pay attention to form factor) modules.
You have to either use a usb WiFi dongle or purchase a fully usb to mpcie adapter (the only one i found: http://www.mfactors.com/mp1-mini-pci-e-pci-e-adapter-ver-1-0a/ ). Or you can use an old WiFi mpcie module that used the USB interface (intergrated to the mpcie form factor, the same that the 3G and BT modules use)